# How to list all units in systemd regardless of their state including parameterized / templated (@)?

Tags: openvpn, systemd

OpenVPN unit file is parameterized (see `@`):

```
> ls /usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn*
/usr/lib/systemd/system/openvpn@.service
```

The problem is that I cannot list the parameterized service names by `systemctl` command if they are disabled even with option `--all`:

```
> systemctl --full --all -t service | grep openvpn
```

However, I can still list names of non-parameterized disabled services (`iptables` in this example):

```
> systemctl --full --all -t service | grep iptables
iptables.service loaded inactive dead IPv4 firewall with iptables
```

**How to get list of all units even if some of them are parameterized?**

The question is actually more complicated (I could easily list available unit files to answer myself). However, the problem is in the inconsistency.

- When `openvpn@example.com` service is enabled, it can be listed by the above command.
- When `openvpn@example.com` service is disabled, it cannot.

It seems like an obvious bug (or limitation of the fact that `systemd` does not probably understand whether parameterized service is actually configured when we enable it). However, I rather ask the crowd than jump into this conclusion.

Comment: Command `systemctl --full --all -t service list-unit-files` can list required unit file. However, it is still not the actual full service name which can be used for `systemctl`'s commands `start`, `stop`, ...